# IIS web.config rewrite - Remove specific subfolder from URL

Tags: .net, iis, web-config

How can I remove a specific subdirectory from my URL?

Examples:

[www.mysite.com/web/Login](http://www.mysite.com/web/Login) ➡️ [www.mysite.com/Login](http://www.mysite.com/Login) 
[www.mysite.com/web/Admin/Panel](http://www.mysite.com/web/Admin/Panel) ➡️ [www.mysite.com/Admin/Panel](http://www.mysite.com/Admin/Panel) 
[www.mysite.com/web/Orders](http://www.mysite.com/web/Orders) ➡️ [www.mysite.com/Orders](http://www.mysite.com/Orders)

I already tried

```xml
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="removeWeb" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^web/(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```

but no success.

For context, this is a .NET Framework site being reached by a .NET Core site with YARP proxy.

Comment: You misunderstood how to compose rewrite rules. The pattern in `match` tag should cover the shortened URLs, and the long/original URLs should be covered in `action` tag. Please carefully analyze the examples, and then you should know what I am talking about and help yourself out, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear the cache and try again, if it still doesn't work, you can try the following rule:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
     <rule name="Remove web" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*(web)(.+)" />
        <action type="Redirect" url=http://www.mytest.com{R:2} appendQueryString="false" />
     </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Mysite cannot be used in post, so I use test instead.